# Why doesn't the compiler let me set a property of a readonly struct?

Tags: c#, struct

The following code doesn't compile, with `CS1612 Cannot modify the return value of 'S2.S1' because it is not a variable`:

```
void Main()
{
    var s2 = new S2();
    s2.S1.Field = 1; //error on this line
}

readonly struct S1
{
    public readonly int Field { set { } }
}

readonly struct S2
{
    readonly S1 s1;
    public readonly S1 S1 => s1;
}
```

If the structs wouldn't be `readonly`, I understand why the compiler wouldn't let, but now that they are `readonly`, it's completely safe to access the property.

Please don't mark as a duplicate of questions that involve structs that are not `readonly` - with those it is indeed meaningless to change a field on a return value, as the struct is simply a copy.

What's more, the following works fine:

```
void Main()
{
    var s2 = new S2();
    s2.s1.Field = 1; //accessing the field here instead of the property
}

readonly struct S1
{
    public readonly int Field { set { } }
}

readonly struct S2
{
    public readonly S1 s1;
    public readonly S1 S1 => s1;
}
```

Why doesn't the compiler let my first example?

(This is a minimum, reproducible example. In my real life case, `S1` wraps a class, and has properties that delegate to the wrapped class, and I can't see a reason why `C#` should block me.)

Based on the comments, I will give a clearer example of why `readonly` should prevent the error:

```
void Main()
{
    GetS1().Field = 1; //this produces an error
    GetS2().Field = 1; //this compiles fine
}

struct S1
{
    public int Field { set { } }
}

readonly struct S2
{
    public int Field { set { } }
}

S1 GetS1()=>new S1();
S2 GetS2()=>new S2();
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216211/discussion-on-question-by-wezten-why-doesnt-the-compiler-let-me-set-a-property).